# json_modify with json_query add 2 rows

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a problem, when add a lot rows with json_modify with json_query just add 1 and not all rows.
Thanks so much, greetings

```
   DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[
{"OrderNumber":"SO43659","OrderDate":"2011-05-31T00:00:00","AccountNumber":"AW29825","ItemPrice":2024.9940,"ItemQuantity":1}]'
--{"OrderNumber":"SO43661","OrderDate":"2011-06-01T00:00:00","AccountNumber":"AW73565","ItemPrice":2024.9940,"ItemQuantity":3}]'

drop table if exists #t01 ;
create table #t01 (OrderNumber varchar(10), OrderDate date, AccountNumber varchar(10), ItemPrice money, ItemQuantity int)

insert #t01 select 'SO43662', getdate(), 'AW73569', 64.45,2
insert #t01 select 'SO43699', getdate(), 'AX73569', 34.45,6
insert #t01 select 'SO43899', getdate(), 'AX73588', 4.45,3

declare @njs nvarchar(max)
set @njs = (select * from #t01 for json auto , WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)
select @njs 
select @json 
set @json = JSON_MODIFY (@json,'append $',JSON_QUERY(@njs))
select @json -- just add 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `CONCAT` function

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
{"OrderNumber":"SO43659","OrderDate":"2011-05-31T00:00:00","AccountNumber":"AW29825","ItemPrice":2024.9940,"ItemQuantity":1},
{"OrderNumber":"SO43661","OrderDate":"2011-06-01T00:00:00","AccountNumber":"AW73565","ItemPrice":2024.9940,"ItemQuantity":3}'

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #T01 ;
CREATE TABLE #T01 (OrderNumber varchar(10), OrderDate date, AccountNumber varchar(10), ItemPrice money, ItemQuantity int)

INSERT #T01 SELECT N'SO43662', GETDATE(), 'AW73569', 64.45,2
INSERT #T01 SELECT N'SO43699', GETDATE(), 'AX73569', 34.45,6
INSERT #T01 SELECT N'SO43899', GETDATE(), 'AX73588', 4.45,3

DECLARE @njs NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @njs = (SELECT * FROM #T01 FOR JSON AUTO,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)

SELECT @njs=CONCAT('{"Order":[',@JSON,',',@njs,']}')

SELECT @json=JSON_QUERY(@njs,'$.Order')

SELECT @json
```

Using `JSON_MODIFY` function

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
[{"OrderNumber":"SO43659","OrderDate":"2011-05-31T00:00:00","AccountNumber":"AW29825","ItemPrice":2024.9940,"ItemQuantity":1},
{"OrderNumber":"SO43661","OrderDate":"2011-06-01T00:00:00","AccountNumber":"AW73565","ItemPrice":2024.9940,"ItemQuantity":3}]'

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #T01 ;
CREATE TABLE #T01 (OrderNumber varchar(10), OrderDate date, AccountNumber varchar(10), ItemPrice money, ItemQuantity int)

INSERT #T01 SELECT N'SO43662', GETDATE(), 'AW73569', 64.45,2
INSERT #T01 SELECT N'SO43699', GETDATE(), 'AX73569', 34.45,6
INSERT #T01 SELECT N'SO43899', GETDATE(), 'AX73588', 4.45,3

DECLARE @njs NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @njs = (SELECT * FROM #T01 FOR JSON AUTO,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)

SELECT @njs=CONCAT('[',@njs,']')

SELECT @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json,'append $', JSON_QUERY([value]))
FROM OPENJSON(@njs)

SELECT @json
```

Output:

```
[  {"OrderNumber":"SO43659","OrderDate":"2011-05-31T00:00:00","AccountNumber":"AW29825","ItemPrice":2024.9940,"ItemQuantity":1},  
   {"OrderNumber":"SO43661","OrderDate":"2011-06-01T00:00:00","AccountNumber":"AW73565","ItemPrice":2024.9940,"ItemQuantity":3},
  {"OrderNumber":"SO43662","OrderDate":"2021-03-17","AccountNumber":"AW73569","ItemPrice":64.4500,"ItemQuantity":2},
  {"OrderNumber":"SO43699","OrderDate":"2021-03-17","AccountNumber":"AX73569","ItemPrice":34.4500,"ItemQuantity":6},
  {"OrderNumber":"SO43899","OrderDate":"2021-03-17","AccountNumber":"AX73588","ItemPrice":4.4500,"ItemQuantity":3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are trying to do is add multiple items to an array. You cannot do this with `JSON_MODIFY` in a single call.

Instead, you are better off breaking out the original JSON with `OPENJSON`, concatenating it with the new data and rebuilding the array:

```sql
select cast((

select OrderNumber, OrderDate, AccountNumber, ItemPrice, ItemQuantity 
from #t01
union all
select OrderNumber, OrderDate, AccountNumber, ItemPrice, ItemQuantity
from openjson(@JSON) WITH (
   OrderNumber nvarchar(100),
   OrderDate nvarchar(100),
   AccountNumber nvarchar(100),
   ItemPrice decimal,
   ItemQuantity int
)
for json auto

) as nvarchar(max));
```